# Private chain for private company stock registration with Ethereum

Tags: private-blockchain

If I want to test for establishing private chain for private company stock registration instead of purly mining, meanwhile administrator's permission also need. Would you advice me how to do that. what technology does Ethereum use for supporting doing that. Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum. Could you please specify your problem. Have you already tried running a private chain? What is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You need at least one miner to have a functional private network otherwise transactions wouldn't be validated and added to the block chain. To run a [single](https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html) node for testing purposes you do not need administrative/root privileges (all clients as of now bind to port 30303 and store data in user specified directories).